# Why does my python script not recognize speech from audio file?

Tags: google-cloud-speech

I have the following piece of code successfully recognizing short (less than 1 min) test  audio file, but failing with recognition another long audiofile (1.5h).

```py
from google.cloud import speech


def run_quickstart():
    speech_client = speech.Client()
    sample = speech_client.sample(source_uri="gs://linear-arena-2109/zoom0070.flac", encoding=speech.Encoding.FLAC)
    alternatives = sample.recognize('uk-UA')
    for alternative in alternatives:
        print(u'Transcript: {}'.format(alternative.transcript))

    with open("Output.txt", "w") as text_file:
        for alternative in alternatives:
            text_file.write(alternative.transcript.encode('utf8'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_quickstart()
```

Both files are uploaded to **Google Cloud**.

The first one:
https://storage.googleapis.com/linear-arena-2109/sample.flac

The second one: 
https://storage.googleapis.com/linear-arena-2109/zoom0070.flac

Both were converted from mp3 with `ffmpeg` utility:

```
ffmpeg -i sample.mp3 -ac 1 sample.flac
ffmpeg -i zoom0070.mp3 -ac 1 zoom0070.flac
```

First file was successfully recognized, but second file outputs the following error:

```
google.gax.errors.RetryError: GaxError(Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient, caused by <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT, Sync input too long. For audio longer than 1 min use LongRunningRecognize with a 'uri' parameter.)>)
```

But I have already used `uri` parameter in my python script. What is wrong?

**update**

@NieDzejkob helped to understand the error. So, method `long_running_recognize` should be used instead of `recognize`. The comprehensive `long_running_recognize` usage example can be found on the corresponding [document page](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/async-recognize#speech-async-recognize-gcs-python)

Comment: Read the error message for the answer.

Comment: You are right. A method `long_running_recognize` should be used instead. I have fixed the code. My audio file is processing by `google-cloud-speech` at the moment.

Answer (score 16):

For any audio file longer than 1 minute, you need to use Asynchronous Speech Recognition ***and*** the file has to be uploaded to Google Cloud Storage so that you can pass in a `gcs_uri`.

In addition, you will need to use the `.long_running_recognize` method in your script. An example from GCP documentation can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/async-recognize#speech-async-recognize-gcs-python).

I realize that OP figured it out but thought it would be useful to provide an answer and generalize it a bit.